# Dynamically change parameter of a struts2 url

Tags: java, url, parameters, tags, struts2

I'm having problems to dynamically assign a parameter to a url in struts2 framework.
I'm struggling with this for a couple of days and I can't put it to work.
A little background, I'm doing a web application using struts2, I also use JQuery plugin.
I have two autocomplete which I need to be linked to each other, the best way I found to do so, is to pass the id of the choosen item on the first autocompleter to the second one to narrow its options.

So what I'm doing is something like this, as stated here http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/url.html

```
<s:url id="contactsautocompleterurl" action="contacts-autocompleter">
    <s:param name="companyId" value="%{companyId}"></s:param>
</s:url>

<s:hidden id="contact_company_id" name="companyId"></s:hidden>
```

I set the value of the hidden field with JQuery and I can see that the value is being changed. My problem is to get that value into the parameter. I've also tried like this and still nothing

```
<s:param name="companyId" value="%{contact_company_id}"></s:param>
```

I'm sure I'm missing a tiny detail, hope someone can point it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you, but I think you can't do it with "s:" tags, since these are processed server-side on page generation, and cannot be processed again once the page has finished loading.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. The hidden field had to be set on the server side.

regards

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to build the URL with jQuery client side. You can create the URL with the s:url tag and manipulate it in the javascript once your selections are made on the page.

```
<s:url id="contactsautocompleterurl" action="contacts-autocompleter" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var actionURL = '<s:property value="%{contactsautocompleterurl}" />';

    $('#companyIdSelect').change(function(){
        var companyIDvalue = $(this).val();
        actionURL += '?companyId=' + companyIDvalue;
     });
</script>
```

This should produce results like you're looking for, you then just assign the actionURL javascript variable to where ever you need it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that should probably do the trick, but i already managed to guess what was wrong. 
I had to set the hidden id before the page was rendered, which i wasn't doing, i was only setting the hidden value via jquery on client side, and the hidden field had to be set on the server side. The other workarround is the one you suggested.

Thanks a lot